# Windows 8 geolocation change at the OS level

Tags: windows-8-preview, geolocation

My default Windows 8 geolocation is set to Chicago, IL.  Not 'cause I want it to be, but because my wireless broadband provider is providing an IP address that is based out of Chicago, IL.  With the exception of turning off geolocation sensors in each browser and turning off Windows 8 location sharing all together, is there a way to change the Windows 8 default (geolocation/graphical) location?  Similar to Windows 7 "Region and Language" & "Location and Other Sensors" through the Control Panel.  Windows 8 loses these options, providing only "Region" & "Location Settings", neither of which provide you the ability to change location at the City and Street level.  Any answers, suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

Typing "Sensors" at the Start Screen offers the "Locations Settings" control panel, where you can disable the Windows Location platform.

Comment: Thank you.  You are absolutely correct.  I can turn it off.  But, unlike Windows 7, I can't manually enter a street address and city.  In Windows 8, you are basically limited to 'United States'.  After doing as much searching as I have done, I believe the answer to my question is 'NO'.  Unfortunate, it is.

Answer (score -2):

While you may not be able to change your location at the OS level, you can [spoof your location](https://mvark.blogspot.com/2012/10/geolocation-spoofing-with-windows-8.html) using the [Windows 8 Simulator](https://web.archive.org/web/20151108021002/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/davrous/archive/2012/07/10/using-the-windows-8-simulator-amp-vs-2012-to-debug-the-ie10-touch-events-amp-your-responsive-design.aspx)

Comment: He is a normal user not a developer testing a feature within his program.