# Can you change your location in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, geolocation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows 8 geolocation change at the OS level](https://superuser.com/questions/418951/windows-8-geolocation-change-at-the-os-level)

I have installed Windows 8 and I'm connected through cable. The location services thinks I am somewhere close, but not especially.

So, is there some way I can correct my location so that the maps app and others using location services will get my correct location?

Comment: The accuracy of your location depends on how the Windows Location Provider determines your location - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464919.aspx. As you're connected over cable, it probably uses your IP address to determine location which is not as effective as Wi-Fi triangulation. While you may not be able to change your location at the OS level, you can spoof your location using the Windows 8 Simulator - http://mvark.blogspot.com/2012/10/geolocation-spoofing-with-windows-8.html

Answer (score 0):

From [this previous question](https://superuser.com/questions/418951/windows-8-geolocation-change-at-the-os-level), it would appear that manually setting your location is not possible in Windows 8.

Pulling up "Change Location" in settings allows you to select your country, and that's as granular as you can get with manual adjustments.
[image: Windows 8 Change Location Options]